# Usage of CASE in MySQL

Tags: mysql, case

Can I use case with the input I pass to the query?
Example:

```
select distinct tp.*
  from kat_task_property tp
    inner join kat_task_to_workstream ttw
      on ttw.ttw_frn_task_id = tp.tp_frn_task_id
        and ttw.ttw_frn_workstream_id= :workStreamId
        and ttw.ttw_ended_by is null
        and tp.tp_ended_by is null
        and tp.tp_is_active=true
        and ttw.ttw_is_active=true
    left join kat_user_to_task_order kto
      on ttw.ttw_id = kto.uto_frn_task_to_workstream_id
        and kto.uto_frn_user_id = :userId
  order by tp.tp_completed_at ,kto.uto_order
  limit :index, :size
```

In the above sql query, can I use case using the value index has?

I.e., if index is not equal to 0, I want this query to be executed, else I want other query to be executed.

**EDIT:** For the first page, I need records which are independent of limit, i.e., it should not consider pagination. From, second page onwards, it should paginate as per limit.

Comment: the question is not very clear. what java and spring data has to do with this query?

Comment: and yes, in theory you can.

Comment: @Sarief How to do that?

Comment: Are you maybe having an [xy-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)? You should maybe ask about your actual problem, instead of asking how to maybe do what you think the solution is. I would guess that you want to know how many results you have in total, so you can display e.g. the number of pages. And your solution is to just get all results the first time.